# why does my book say "Los tacos son ricos"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

I came across the usage "los tacos *son* ricos"? Does that mean that they are rich instead of tasting good? Is this correct? I thought that one had to use *estar* in this context.

Answer (score 9):

Both *Los tacos son ricos* and *Los tacos están ricos* are correct, but they mean slightly different things. As you probably already know, the verb "ser" is generally used for permanent qualitites and the verb "estar" is generally used for states, although there are many exceptions. So, what difference does it make to use "ser" or "estar" when speaking about taste?

As a rule of thumb, "estar" is used to emphasize the idea that something is tasty in a given occasion, but that that's not necessarily always true. "Ser" is used when the meal you're talking about is general or unspecific. For example:

> La comida de mi colegio no **es** rica, pero los tacos que sirven hoy **están** ricos.

"La comida de mi colegio" isn't describing a specific meal in a specific occasion, so "ser" is used. "Los tacos que sirven hoy" is specific: it's not any food and it's not any tacos, but "today's tacos", so "estar" is the most appropriate choice.

So:

> Los tacos son ricos => Tacos, as a general thing, are good/tasty.
>   Los tacos están ricos => Some specific tacos are good/tasty. <sub>See below for further clarification</sub>

When you say "Los tacos están ricos" you aren't necessarily saying other tacos aren't good, but you aren't saying they are good either. You are just talking about some specific tacos, without mentioning tacos as a general category of food. It's also worth to note that this difference in meaning is really subtle. When describing a meal you are having right now and you want to say it's good, only "estar" sounds natural, but when you're describing a general thing, both "ser" and "estar" sound natural to a native speaker ear. For example, say A offers you some papaya juice and then asks you:

> A: ¿Qué tal el jugo de papaya?
>   You: **Está** muy rico, gracias. (You wouldn't say *es* muy rico in this case)

Now, say you're talking with A about your likes and dislikes and A asks you:

> A: ¿Te gusta el jugo de papaya?
>   You: Sí, **es** muy rico. (Here, both "ser" and "estar" would actually sound natural)

So in the first example "La comida de mi colegio no *es* rica" would be just as correct as "La comida de mi colegio no *está* rica". The same thing applies to the second example: if you say "Los tacos están ricos" you may be speaking about some specific or unspecific tacos, and there's no way to know without further context.

In conclusion, use only "estar" with specific things, but when talking about the taste of unspecific things, verb choice doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It actually means the opposite of what you guessed.

### They taste good / great!

A more memorable way to think of it is that, in English, we also call food rich.  Rich in flavor, rich in taste, rich in sweetness, etc...

While sometimes in English we call food "rich" in a negative sense, it is always a "good adjective" when describing food in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't provide the grammar rules, but as a native Spanish speaker, some educated, I can tell you this:

"Rico", or "ricos", could mean tasty or rich (wealthy). If you translate it literally, it could be wrong. The meaning/correct word comes from the context where it's used. Yes, in Spanish it's correct.

It's also correct to say "Los tacos están ricos".

Another example for this could be: "Uranio enriquecido" translated to English "Enriched uranium" same as "enriched flour" / "harina enriquecida".

Regarding the verb *to be*, *ser o estar* in Spanish, I've found that *ser* is for permanent or stable in the long term situations. Like "I'm from Bolivia", means "Yo soy de Bolivia". It's something that will not change in time, or circumstances. However, if you say "I'm hungry" / "Yo tengo hambre", that will soon change as soon as you eat a good meal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

"Los tacos son ricos" is the way South American speakers say "Tacos are tasty".

"Los tacos están ricos" is the way Spanish people refer to it.

Basically, two things here:

1. Ricos: in this case, it means "tasty" instead of rich, because of the context
2. "Ser" is used in South America while "estar" is commonly used in Spain

In Spain, usually they don't say "La comida de mi colegio no es rica", however they say "La comida de mi colegio no está rica", both meaning the same.

Comment: This is utterly wrong. Both *ser* or *estar* are used in Spanish language. No matter the place you are.

Comment: well, as a native Spanish speaker, I think we have different accents in South America and Spain, but if you think you know more than me, congrats...

Comment: @BehindTheSciences, FYI Ustanak is a native Spanish speaker. I'm also a native Spanish speaker and you are wrong. Being natives does not make us experts. We have a lot to learn from many very knowledgeable people around here. Please read Yey's answer.

Comment: I added another example. I think in this case, both "ser" and "estar" can be used and there is no need to confuse to much someone that is learning Spanish

Comment: In Spain people would say "La comida de mi colegio no está **buena**". They would use "estar" because "bueno" is an ambiguous word and verb choice (ser bueno vs estar bueno) resolves that ambiguity. I don't think there's a difference in usage with "rico" on both sides of the pond.

Comment: @Yay no one said that they is a difference in usage with "rico"

Comment: You said "'Ser' is used in South America while 'estar' is commonly used in Spain". I'm saying that when using "rico" there's no difference regarding what verb is used (ser vs estar), but that "rico" isn't a term Spaniards would normally use anyway.

Comment: @Yay In Spain we don't normally say "La comida es buena/rica (the food is good)" but we say "La comida está buena/rica". Make a survey asking that and you will see how I am right :)

Comment: *la comida es buena* is normally said when refering to the food given in a restaurant, for example.

Comment: @Ustanak that's true, but coming back to the question, the general use of ser/estar to say "a specific food/dish is good", in Spain we say "una comida en concreto/plato está bueno"... I don't see any more useful issues on this matter to discuss and you already voted negatively my answer using your opinions as justification... but just to be clear, I'm very confident and happy with my answer because all that I did was adding a point about the lexical differences between Spanish-speaking countries which is useful for people that learn the language.